# AngularJS not reading Iframe element on REST

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rendering

My webpage is not reading only the Iframe tag. I have no idea why.
The content is being sent correctly, as I checked on postman.

This is the content I'm receiving from Postman:

```
 "Conteudo": "<p>Test iframe:</p>\n\n<p><iframe frameborder=\"0\" height=\"300\" scrolling=\"no\" src=\"https://www.express.co.uk/news/science/923166/space-news-supernova-birth-astronomy-victor-buso\" width=\"300\"></iframe></p>\n\n<p>&nbsp;</p>\n\n<p>Check it OUt</p>\n",
```

I have no idea why there are some "\" on the html anyways.

However, when displaying the same content on my console, I receive the following result:

```
<p>Test iframe:</p>
<p>
<iframe frameborder="0" height="300" scrolling="no" src="https://www.express.co.uk/news/science/923166/space-news-supernova-birth-astronomy-victor-buso" width="300"></iframe>
</p>

<p>Check it OUt</p>
```

but when displaying on HTML, I receive the following empty element:
[image: Unknown error]

I'm kinda confused on what is going on. Could anyone explain to me why my navigator cant render the responde on html?

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell Angular that the content is safe by running [`$sce.trustAsHtml`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce#trustAsHtml) on your HTML string before binding it.  See the snippet below.

```js
angular
  .module('myApp', [])
  .controller('myController', ['$scope', '$sce', function($scope, $sce) {
    $scope.Noticia = {};
    
    var content = "<p>Test iframe:</p>\n\n<p><iframe frameborder=\"0\" height=\"300\" scrolling=\"no\" src=\"https://www.express.co.uk/news/science/923166/space-news-supernova-birth-astronomy-victor-buso\" width=\"300\"></iframe></p>\n\n<p>&nbsp;</p>\n\n<p>Check it OUt</p>\n";
    
    $scope.loadContent = function() {
      $scope.Noticia.Conteudo = $sce.trustAsHtml(content);
    }
  }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
  <div ng-bind-html="Noticia.Conteudo"></div>  

  <button type="button" ng-click="loadContent()">Load Content</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks mate! I did something slightly different  but using the same principle and with SCE, worked like a charm! Thank you so much for it.